# Getting Custom Server Control src into a jQuery array once images are loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create a server control that returns a different image once all of the images of a certain class have been loaded. The count on the images is coming back fine so I know they're being picked up.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get the item's source into the array to then check and manipulate it in the "Do Stuff" block. They're all just coming through empty. I have also tried using `this.src` in place of `this.getAttribute("src");` but that doesn't seem to be working either. I am pretty sure that in this case, it's because 'this' is refering to the class, no the image that belongs to the class, am I on the right track for this? If so, how might one attain that image source?

```
var images = []; //Create the image array

//Get the images on this page, add them to the array
$(".image-to-be-reloaded").each(function (i) {
    images[i] = this.getAttribute("src");
    console.log(images[i]);
});

var number = images.length; //Used to check the number of image items is correct

//Check that all images on the page have already loaded
load_counter = 0; //Reset start values
$(images).each(function (i, item) {
    $(item).load(function () {
        load_counter++;
        if (load_counter === images.length) {

            //All items have loaded - Do stuff!
            alert("Whehey!");
            images[i] = "imagenumber" + i;
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the second argument with each:

```
each(function (i,ele) {
    ele.getAttribute("src");
...
```

or have a look at the documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/each/